# Ratio of two Jensen's Inequality

Tags: convex-analysis, expected-value, ratio, jensen-inequality

I have these pair of numbers
$ (a, b) = (\frac{4}{9}, \frac{1}{9}) $ and $(c, d) = (\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{6}) $. (Number mean nothing, just for illustration and simplification)

Note that - (a, b) are pair of numbers which represent $((E(e_1))^2, (E(e_2))^2) $ and (c, d) are pair for $((E(e_1^2)), (E(e_2^2))) $

Where, E is the expectation.

Clearly, c>a and d>b (by Jensen inequality)   But when I divide $\frac{a}{b}$ and $\frac{c}{d}$, I get $\frac{a}{b}$ > $\frac{c}{d}$.

So, does Jensen's inequality flips when two Jensen inequality are divided?

Is there a property which ensure that this will be true always.

Please help